# Getting Permission Denied error trying to move Google Analytis property

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to move ownership of a Google Analytics account (property) to a client that has moved on to a new company. I have had them setup a new analytics account and add me as a user to the account with all permissions checked. When I go into the admin of their current account, that I own, and go to the move property screen, I can see the new account they created. After I select the new account, check confirm changes and click the blue "Start Move" I just get a red notification at the top of the screen that says "Permission Denied".

- They have added me to their new account and given me all the
  privileges.
- Both accounts are standard free acounts, not 360 accounts
- No AdWords, AdSense, etc are linked to either account.

Any ideas what I could be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. My work around was:

1. Go into Admin in the Source account (your GA account)
2. Create a new account i.e. "My new temp account"
3. Move your Property to "My new temp account"
4. Grant your client the relevant permissions to "My new temp account"
5. Move the Property from "My new temp account" to the Destination account (the client's account)

It moved successfully after that. I don't know why I got "Permission denied" originally. The site I was moving was very old (10+ years), so might have been a "legacy" issue with the Google account, but that's me guessing!

Comment: I was excited that your fix might have worked. But I still get permission denied :(

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks